# numpy divide by zero results

Tags: python, numpy

When divide different dividends by zero, I got different results.

```
arr = np.array([0.0, 1.0, -0.1])
print(arr/0)
```

The results are following

```
[ nan  inf -inf]
```

Why? I expect the results were all `nan`.

BTW, I got two types of warning.

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
```

Comment: "I expect the results were all nan" - why? This is completely normal IEEE 754 floating point behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 OK, so this is the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IEEE 754 defines division by zero as follows:

> a ÷ +0 is positive infinity when a is positive, negative infinity when a is negative, and NaN when a = ±0.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#Computer_arithmetic

Comment: Not sure if you're the right person to ask, but why does python stop immediately and throw an exception if you type `x/0` but allow execution to complete when this operation is undertaken in numpy?  I would have wasted much less time if numpy had forced me to confront the ZeroDivisionError if I had known that was the problem and it had spit out a line number instead of letting my program terminate with weird results

Comment: @frank I'm guessing numpy by default uses float64 as a numeric type, and integers and floating numbers act differently to division by zero.
When integers are divided by zero, python throws a error because it is an undefined operation, whereas floating numbers divided by zero is defined as above.

Comment: I don't think so. I just entered `1/0.` in my python2.7 console and it spit out `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

Comment: @frank After some searching, I'm guessing it's just a matter of language design. Numpy complies with the IEEE 754, whereas python doesn't and throws an exception.

Comment: Oh well.  I know it's not your doing.  It was just inconvenient in my debugging

Comment: FWIW, you can get numpy to throw on a divide by zero using np.seterr()

See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html